# Why the Euler Transformation converges more quickly?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, numerical-methods, generating-functions

There is a problem I've met.

I already know that the Leibniz series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$ converges to $\frac{\pi}{4}$, but it does very slowly.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration#Euler%27s_transform) says that Euler Transformation makes the series converge more quickly. Its transformation is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2)^n(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$.

By python programming, I confirmed that it converges more quickly than original one, but I don't know why it happens. Wikipedia does not give me a precise proof of rapid convergence.

I found [a document](http://www.worldpifederation.org/Fed/euler.pdf) that proves the rapidity of convergence. In the document, however, does not give existence of such weight function $w(t)$, satisfying $\int_0^1 t^k w(t)dt=a_k$.

Hence, the question is that, "is there a proof for rapid convergence of Euler transformation?"

Thanks.

Comment: $2n+1$ is a lot smaller than $\frac{(2n+1)!}{n!}$, that's why one series converges a lot faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof of rapid convergence of the Euler transformation applicable to the series
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}&=1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\cdots\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1\cdot 2}{3\cdot 5}+\frac{1\cdot2\cdot 3}{3\cdot 5\cdot 7}+\cdots\right)\\
\end{align*}
is given by Konrad Knopp in *[Theory and Application of Infinite Series](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/theory-and-application-of-infinite-series)* in section 155.

In order to see what's going on we need to know what is meant by *rapid convergence*. We find in section 166 the following definition:

> - *Definition 1:* Given two convergent series $\sum c_n=s$ and $\sum c_n^{\prime}=s^{\prime}$ of positive terms, whose partial sums are denoted by $s_n$ and $s_n^{\prime}$, the corresponding remainders by $s-s_n=r_n, s^{\prime}-s_n^{\prime}=r_n^{\prime}$, we say that the second converges **more or less rapidly** (or better or less well) than the first, according as
>   \begin{align*}
>   \lim\frac{r_n^{\prime}}{r_n}=0\qquad\quad\text{or}\qquad\quad\lim\frac{r_n^{\prime}}{r_n}=+\infty,
>   \end{align*}
>
> If the limit of this ratio exists and has a *finite positive* value, or if it be known merely that its lower limit $> 0$ and its upper limit $< +\infty$, then the convergence of the two series will be said **of the same kind**. In any other case a comparison of the rapidity of convergence of the two series is impracticable.

The following theorem is stated for series which are *fully monotone*. These are series for which *all* the differences $\Delta^k a_n\ (k,n=0,1,2,\ldots)$ are positive.

> - *Theorem 1:* If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^na_n$ is an alternating series for which the (positive) numbers $a_0, a_1,\ldots$ form a fully monotone null sequence, while, from the first, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\geq a>\frac{1}{2}$ (for every $n$), then the transformed series $\sum\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\Delta^n a_0$ converges more rapidly than the given series.

The proof given by K. Knopp goes as follows:

> *Proof:* Since $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\geq a$, we have $a_n\geq a_0\cdot a^n$. Further, for the remainder $\gamma_n$ of the given series we have
> \begin{align*}
> (-1)^{n+1}r_n=a_{n+1}-a_{n+2}+-\cdots=\Delta a_{n+1}+\Delta a_{n+3}+\Delta a_{n+5}+\cdots
> \end{align*}
> Since $\left(\Delta a_{\nu}\right)$ is itself a monotone null sequence,
> \begin{align*}
> |r_n|\geq \frac{1}{2}\left(\Delta a_{n+1}+\Delta a_{n+2}+\Delta a_{n+3}+\cdots\right)=\frac{1}{2}a_{n+1}
> \geq \frac{1}{2}a_0\cdot a^{n+1}
> \end{align*}
> On the other hand, as $\Delta^n a_0-\Delta^{n+1} a_0=\Delta^n a_1\geq 0$, the numerators of the transformed series also form a monotone null sequence, and in particular are all $\leq a_0$.
>
> Consequently the remainders $\gamma_n^{\prime}$ of the transformed series, - which, moreover, is a series of positive terms, - satisfy
> \begin{align*}
> r_n^{\prime}=\frac{\Delta^{n+1} a_0}{2^{n+2}}+\cdots
> \leq \frac{a_0}{2^{n+2}}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots\right)=\frac{a_0}{2^{n+1}}
> \end{align*}
> Consequently, we have
> \begin{align*}
> \left|\frac{r_n^{\prime}}{r_n}\right|\leq\frac{1}{a}\left(\frac{1}{2a}\right)^n,
> \end{align*}
> which proves the theorem.

*Note:* A paper with some other interesting discussions of the rapidity of convergence is *[Transformations to Speed the Convergence of Series](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/46/jresv46n1p56_A1b.pdf)* by J. B. Rosser from 1951.

Answer (score 3):

Since the relevance of $\int_0^1t^kw(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=a_k$ is not clear, I  present a proof of the Euler Series Transformation.

---

**Lemma $\bf{1}$:**

For all non-negative integer $k$,
$$
\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2^{n+1}}=1\tag1
$$
**Proof:**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2^{n+1}}x^k
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2^{n+1}}x^k\tag{2a}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(x+1)^n}{2^{n+1}}\tag{2b}\\
&=\frac12\frac{1}{1-(x+1)/2}\tag{2c}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{1}{1-x}\tag{2d}\\[3pt]
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\tag{2e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: Multiply the sum by $x^k$ and sum, then change the order of summation
$\text{(2b)}$: sum in $k$ using the Binomial Theorem
$\text{(2c)}$: sum in $n$ using a Geometric Series
$\text{(2d)}$: simplify
$\text{(2e)}$: write as a geometric series

Equating the coefficients of $x^k$ in $(2)$ proves the Lemma.
$\large\square$

**Lemma $\bf{2}$:**

For any non-negative integer $N$,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^N\sum_{n=k}^N2^{-n-1}\left[\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n}{k+1}\right]=1-2^{-N-1}\tag3
$$
Furthermore, for any non-negative integers $k$ and $N$,
$$
\sum_{n=k}^N2^{-n-1}\left[\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n}{k+1}\right]\ge0\tag{4}
$$
**Proof:**
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^N\sum_{n=k}^N2^{-n-1}\left[\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n}{k+1}\right]\tag{5a}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^N\sum_{k=0}^n2^{-n-1}\left[\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n}{k+1}\right]\tag{5b}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^N2^{-n-1}[2^n-(2^n-1)]\tag{5c}\\[6pt]
&=1-2^{-N-1}\tag{5d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(5b)}$: change the order of summation
$\text{(5c)}$: Binomial Theorem
$\text{(5d)}$: sum the geometric series

$(5)$ proves $(3)$.

Lemma $1$ implies that
$$
\sum_{n=k}^\infty2^{-n-1}\left[\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n}{k+1}\right] = 1-1 = 0\tag6
$$
Note that
$$
\binom{n}{k+1}=\frac{n-k}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}\tag7
$$
Therefore, under the conditions above that $0\le k\le n$, the terms in $(6)$ are positive when $n\lt2k+1$ and then negative when $n\gt2k+1$.  Since the sum in $(6)$ is $0$, all of its partial sums must be positive.
$\large\square$

**Corollary $\bf{2.1}$:**
$$
\sum_{k=0}^N\left|\sum_{n=k}^N2^{-n-1}\left[\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n}{k+1}\right]\right|=1-2^{-N-1}\tag8
$$
**Proof:**

Since the partial sum inside the absolute value is always positive, this is the same sum as in Lemma $2$.
$\large\square$

**Theorem (Euler Series Transformation):**

If
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\tag9
$$
converges, then
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{-n-1}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a_k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\tag{10}
$$
**Proof (Euler Series Transformation):**

Formally, we would simply like to use Lemma $1$ after switching the order of summation.  However, the sum of $a_k$ may not converge absolutely, so we must switch the order of summation with care.

Let $S_k$ be the partial sum
$$
S_k=\sum_{j=0}^ka_j\tag{11}
$$
and $S$ be the limit of $S_k$ as $k\to\infty$.

Then, $a_k=S_k-S_{k-1}$. This yields the partial sum
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=0}^N2^{-n-1}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a_k\tag{12a}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^N2^{-n-1}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(S_k-S_{k-1})\tag{12b}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^N2^{-n-1}\sum_{k=0}^n\left[\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n}{k+1}\right]S_k\tag{12c}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^N\sum_{n=k}^N2^{-n-1}\left[\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n}{k+1}\right]S_k\tag{12d}
\end{align}
$$
Pick an $\epsilon\gt0$.  Choose an $M$ so that $|S_k - S|\lt\epsilon$ for all $k\ge M$ and so that $2^{-M-1}\lt\epsilon$.  Lemma $1$ implies that for each non-positive integer $k$,
$$
\sum_{n=k}^\infty2^{-n-1}\left[\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n}{k+1}\right]=1-1=0\tag{13}
$$
Choose an $N\ge M$ so that for all $m\ge N$ and $k\lt M$,
$$
\left|\,\sum_{n=k}^m2^{-n-1}\left[\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n}{k+1}\right]\,\right|\lt\frac{\epsilon}{M}\tag{14}
$$
Now we have
$$
\begin{align}
&\left|\,\left(\sum_{n=0}^N2^{-n-1}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a_k\right)-S\,\,\right|\tag{15a}\\
&=\left|\,\left(\sum_{k=0}^N\sum_{n=k}^N2^{-n-1}\left[\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n}{k+1}\right]S_k\right)-S\,\,\right|\tag{15b}\\
&=\left|\,\left(\sum_{k=0}^N\sum_{n=k}^N2^{-n-1}\left[\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n}{k+1}\right]\left(S_k-S\right)\right)-2^{-N-1}S\,\,\right|\tag{15c}\\
&\le\left|\,\left(\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}\sum_{n=k}^N2^{-n-1}\left[\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n}{k+1}\right]\left(S_k-S\right)\right)\,\right|\tag{15d}\\
&+\left|\,\left(\sum_{k=M}^N\sum_{n=k}^N2^{-n-1}\left[\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n}{k+1}\right]\left(S_k-S\right)\right)\,\right|\tag{15e}\\[9pt]
&+2^{-N-1}\left|\,S\,\right|\tag{15f}\\[12pt]
&=\frac\epsilon{M}M\max_k\left(\left|\,S_k-S\,\right|\right)+\epsilon+\epsilon\left|\,S\,\right|\tag{15g}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(15a)}$: partial sum minus the expected sum
$\text{(15b)}$: apply $(12)$
$\text{(15c)}$: apply Lemma $2$
$\text{(15d)}$: first part of $\text{(15c)}$
$\phantom{\text{(15d):}}$ $(14)$ says that each of the $M$ terms is bounded by $\frac\epsilon{M}$ times $\max_k|S_k-S|$
$\text{(15e)}$: next part of $\text{(15c)}$
$\phantom{\text{(15e):}}$ bounded by Corollary $2.1$ and $|S_k-S|\le\epsilon$
$\text{(15f)}$: last part of $\text{(15c)}$
$\phantom{\text{(15f):}}$ bounded by $2^{-M-1}\le\epsilon$ times $S$
$\text{(15g)}$: triangle inequality

Thus, $(15)$ says that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{-n-1}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a_k=S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\tag{16}
$$
$\large\square$

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Thanks. But does this proof show the rapidity of the transformed series?

Comment: No, but I am planning on adding a section on that. I’ve been away all day, but I’ll be back in an hour or so. I don’t like working on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

You are done once you have found a measure $\mu$ for which $a_n=\int_0^1 t^n\,d\mu$, where $a_n=\frac1{2n+1}$. Hausdorff proved that $\mu$ exists if and only if $a_n$ is completely monotonic, meaning that $a_n$ decreases monotonically to zero, and the differences $a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ increase monotonically to zero, and the second differences $(a_{n+2}-a_{n+1})-(a_{n+1}-a_{n})$ decrease monotonically to zero, and so on for all higher order differences. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_moment_problem for references and more details.

It is indeed true that $a_n=\frac1{2n+1}$ is completely monotonic. Letting $\Delta a_n$ denote $a_{n+1}-a_n$, then
$$
a_n=\frac1{2n+1}\searrow 0
$$
$$
\Delta a_n=\frac1{2n+3}-\frac1{2n+1}=\frac{-2}{(2n+3)(2n+1)}\nearrow 0
$$
$$
\Delta^2 a_n=\frac{-2}{(2n+5)(2n+3)}-\frac{-2}{(2n+3)(2n+1)}=\frac{2\cdot 4}{(2n+5)(2n+3)(2n+1)}\searrow 0
$$
The pattern continues. You can prove by induction that
$$
\Delta^k a_n=(-1)^k\frac{2\cdot 4\cdots (2k)}{(2n+1)(2n+3)\cdots(2n+2k)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case note that $$\frac1{2n+1}=\int_0^1x^{2n}\mathrm dx.$$ Then $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}=\int_0^1\frac1{1+x^2}\mathrm dx.$$ The Euler transform is based on the following series for the integrand:
$$\frac1{1+x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1-x^2)^n}{2^{n+1}}.$$ The $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ partial sum on the right (summing over $n<k$) is a pretty good approximation on the interval $[0,1]$. The greatest difference occurs for $x=0$ and equals $2^{-k}$. Therefore the integral $$\int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{(1-x^2)^n}{2^{n+1}}\mathrm dx$$ is a low estimate for the alternating sum and is off by less than $2^{-k}$. Now this last integral is exactly the $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ partial sum of the Euler transform of the original sequence.